# How many lines are needed to connect all smiling toasters in a 4x4 grid?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization

The puzzle is as follows:

> How many straight lines do you need to draw the least possible to join
> all the smiling toasters if you should not raise the pen or go over
> any line already drawn? Remember that it is allowed to cross.
>
> [image: a 4-by-4 grid of smiling toasters]

The alternatives given are as follows:

1. 6
2. 5
3. 7
4. 4

How should this puzzle be approached? I'm getting 7 lines, however, I think there are different ways. Is there a way to minimize the trials?

I found this riddle in a book *Logical Challenges* from 2000's. It seems to be an adaptation from a reprinted copy of Martin Gardner's Puzzle's book from 1970s.

Because this puzzle has a drawing it **would help if answers also included drawings** so I could properly visualize the lines and understand why they are there.

Comment: [Related](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7831/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-straight-lines-to-connect-all-the-dots-on-this-gri), [related](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/connect-the-dots), [related](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-line-segments-that-need-to-be-made-to-cross-all-po). I haven't found an exact duplicate yet but would be shocked if none existed.

Comment: *I think there are different ways.* - Yes. *Is there a way to minimize the trials?* - Find out what you can do before trying. In the case of this puzzle, the important parts are: you can draw to the outside of the region, and you can draw diagonals. After you realize them, it's just a matter of trying harder until your answer agrees with the book.

Comment: Optimization problems are nasty, and this is also a problem with your questions: we can tell you what you need to realize, and we can tell you what the answer is, but **we cannot tell you *why* it is the answer**, at least logically.

Comment: @Bubbler To your first comment, yes I did several trials and attempted what you mentioned but I still got stuck. I am sorry if I had given the impression of lack of logic. My intented question is to ask a justification how to minimize a certain feature. I know the nature of a puzzle is to be the one who solves it. Perhaps this part I'm not good at. Hence I need guidance. This makes me sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with six lines:

> [image]

It's difficult to tell how I found this, except that I already knew a solution for a 3 by 3 grid with 4 lines, which can be found e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565942/228959) on our sister site Mathematics Stack Exchange. It's also possible that a solution with 5 lines exists.

(By the way, the puzzle is missing the requirement that the lines must be orthogonal or diagonal. Otherwise you can simply do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O8Sk.png), if you extend the lines far enough upwards and downwards.)

Comment: Or I've read somewhere that people get creative with "using a pen which tip width is as wide as the image, so using only one line".

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm accepting your answer. To be honest I had seen a similiar solution for a grid of 3 by 3. Is it okay to assume that if you increase the number of rows so all is a square the number of lines will be one unit less?. Assuming that the requirement is what you mentioned?. By the way, I agree that there is missing a requirement you stated. I was about to ask for the other solution and then I seen your link. That was very clear. I didn't know that the lines *could* cross through the toasters if they were far enough.

Comment: A cleaner additional requirements would be to require that the line pass through the center of the toaster.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this satisfies the intended problem but it follows the rules. I approached it by looking at the minimum multiple choice answer, and trying to exclude solutions of that size.

> [image: 4 lines]

Comment: I mentioned such a solution in my last paragraph – I think the rules of the puzzle as quoted are incomplete.